# Invoke Functions App Callback After User Created in Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is it possible to invoke a Functions App after a user was created in Azure Active Directory?  I'm looking through AAD's settings but am not seeing anything, but it could just be that I don't have enough permissions.  Essentially I'm looking for the Azure equivalent of AWS's Pre Sign-up Lambda Trigger.

Comment: There is no such trigger yet available for Azure Functions. However you could have a look into [streaming Active Directory logs to Azure Event Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/tutorial-azure-monitor-stream-logs-to-event-hub) and then [create an Azure Function with an Event Hub Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=csharp).

Answer (score 0):

Melisco's comment is indeed the best option at the moment. to add a bit of extra information, https://eax360.com/azure-active-directory-capturing-events-in-azure-events-hub/ this example looks for the user creation events specifically.

and here https://medium.com/@the.green.man/trigger-azure-functions-on-event-hub-1e1df0402ba4  is a pretty complete article on one way to trigger a function based on the event hub. 
Hopefully you'll have enough information from that.